# $_POST array is always empty

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I cant figure out why this very simple test of using the input from the form doesnt work..

```
<?php

echo "TEST";

echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";

if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
    $input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
    echo "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="inputText"/>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I display the array it shows that it is empty. When I enter something in the input field and click submit, nothing changes.

[The demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZVNF.png)

I would be very grateful if anyone has an idea, thanks.

[image]

Comment: is the page reloading when you submit? PHP code is only executed when the page loads

Comment: and what happens when you press on submit button?

Comment: The page does reload and the inputfield is reset. But nothing is stored in the array

Answer (score 0):

2 things

SubmitButton needs a value="something" then change

```
   echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
```

to

```
  echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST) . "</pre>";
```

You only need the "true" if you want to return that as a var, like

```
$blob = print_r($_POST, true); 
echo "<pre>" . $blob . "</pre>";
```

Comment: *"SubmitButton needs a value="something""* - that is false.

Comment: do you really think this is the problem? really?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){         what is isset supposed to do with no value? Note:Success! You entered: ".$input; is not in the pic

Comment: If you got rid of the "true" in the print_r then I can only assume that if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){     isn't triggering.  Try a hidden input in your form , input type="hidden" name="click" value="1"     then check for $_POST['click'].. something we know has a value

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem in future (I don't think this is the solution for this specific case):

I was debugging an application and php api since the past 4 hours, printing my output everywhere but I couldn't figure out what the issue was.

The production system was working fine while our testing environment made was not accepting any of my post arrays.

In the end it turned out, that I had a wrong url opened from the application (http:// instead of https://), so a .htaccess file redirected all my requests to https but removed all post information.

Hope this helps anyone.